# MacBook Pro randomly shuts off

Tags: macbook-pro, shutdown, high-sierra

After returning home, I'll take my MacBook Pro out of my bag and plug it in. However, it will often be shut off (never occurred before macOS High Sierra). Obviously, this is a chore, but there seems to be a problem lying within my computer. Anybody know what causes this?

MacBook 13,2
macOS High Sierra, 10.13 (17A362a)
No physical damage

Comment: @Allan It's not there, but this happened last night. If the pattern continues, it'll happen again when I get home.

Comment: I'm still having this issue myself. Unfortunately, the code for the shutdown cause is consistently 5. Any idea why these are 'controlled shutdowns'?

Comment: @HenryGlendening - Shutdown Cause 5 means it's a proper shutdown.  In other words, the computer received the command to shut down and proceeded to do so cleanly.